# Calling 'forge.topbar.setTitle' sometimes causes spontaneous reset on Android 4.1

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I am using forge.setTitle to dynamically change the text of my topbar when my backbone.js application switches views.

Sometimes, doing so causes the Android app to reset on 4.1 Jellybean. I see the trigger.io splash screen again and my app returns to the default view. I am having trouble pinpointing why.

In backbone.js terms, I am calling this function in my Show block for the given view.

```
forge.topbar.setTitle("My new view");
```

It seems to work 'sometimes' which suggests a race condition but I am at a loss as to what could be conflicting.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

I should add that the setTitle function throws its success callback, so no error is detected there.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a trivial test case on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.2 here. It's likely that it's a combination of `setTitle` and other factors causing this problem so some more context is needed. A test case which can illustrate this problem would be great, if it's tricky to narrow down then you can email us at support@trigger.io with a zip of your app or an APK, with a description of the problem and information about the specific device you see it on.

Comment: To anyone having problem like this (unexpected app resets) take a look at the raw device log output with "adb logcat". There may be a stacktrace there which is instructive.